# SQL calculating average for rating with different types

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a thread, and different users rating a movie in 3 different types.

Say i have thread 22, and different types=`movie.quality, movie.story and movie.imdb`

so the structure of the rating table looks like this:

```
| ID | thread_id | user_id | type             | value
| 12 | 22        | 2       | 'movie.imdb'     | 8.5
| 23 | 22        | 4       | 'movie.imdb'     | 7.5
| 42 | 22        | 5       | 'movie.story'    | 8.5
| 56 | 22        | 6       | 'movie.quality'  | 8.5
| 76 | 22        | 6       | 'movie.imdb'     | 7.53
```

as a result of my query, i want to get the average pro id and type, something like

```
array(thread_id=22 => array(
                      type=>movie.imdb =>  average=>8.2),
                      type=>movie.story => average=>8.8),
                      type=>movie.quality => average=>8.1))
```

How can i structure this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do group by thread_id,type and can take AVG of value

```
select thread_id,type, avg (value)
from rating
group by thread_id,type
```

now from the output of this query you can select based on the `thread_id` in your code to make/form the array .. or more precisely array or array ..

Comment: SELECT thread,TYPE, AVG (VALUE),COUNT(*)
FROM rating WHERE thread=25
GROUP BY thread,TYPE; works like a charme, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By grouping:

```
select `type`, avg(`value`)
from ratings
where `thread_id` = 22
group by `type`
```

Comment: based on your answer SELECT TYPE, AVG('value')
FROM rating WHERE thread=25
GROUP BY 'type'; does not work :( = shows average as 0 and shows only one type, not all types.

Comment: That's `\`type\``, not `'type'` - ie. using backticks, not single quotes. It makes a **big** difference.